# Multiple column reassignments based on single condition

Tags: python-polars

Learning polars here and I often come across the pattern where I need to make multiple column reassignments based on a single condition.  In pseudocode it would be something like:

```
    if x=2 then do:
      x='ham'
      y='eggs'
      z='fruit'
    end
```

The following python-polars code works but there has got to be a more elegant way.

```
df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "a": [1,2,3],
        "x": ['foo','bar','baz'],
        "y": ['bar','foo','baz'],
        "z": ['baz','foo','bar']
    }
)
df.with_columns(
    pl.when(pl.col('a')==2).then(pl.lit('ham')).otherwise(pl.col('x')).alias('x'),
    pl.when(pl.col('a')==2).then(pl.lit('eggs')).otherwise(pl.col('y')).alias('y'),
    pl.when(pl.col('a')==2).then(pl.lit('fruit')).otherwise(pl.col('z')).alias('z'),
    
)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The beauty of Polars is that expressions are lazy. They're not evaluated until you run them in the context of an expression. So you can write:

```py
import polars as pl
df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "a": [1,2,3],
        "x": ['foo','bar','baz'],
        "y": ['bar','foo','baz'],
        "z": ['baz','foo','bar']
    }
)
WhenThen = lambda x,y: (
    pl.when(pl.col("a") == 2)
    .then(pl.lit(x))
    .otherwise(pl.col(y))
    .alias(y)
)

df.with_columns(
    WhenThen("ham", "x"),
    WhenThen("eggs", "y"),
    WhenThen("friut", "z")
)
```

This gives:

```py
shape: (3, 4)
┌─────┬─────┬──────┬───────┐
│ a   ┆ x   ┆ y    ┆ z     │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ ---  ┆ ---   │
│ i64 ┆ str ┆ str  ┆ str   │
╞═════╪═════╪══════╪═══════╡
│ 1   ┆ foo ┆ bar  ┆ baz   │
│ 2   ┆ ham ┆ eggs ┆ friut │
│ 3   ┆ baz ┆ baz  ┆ bar   │
└─────┴─────┴──────┴───────┘
```

Answer (score 1):

**TLDR: just use the 2nd code block.**

*The first is a logical step before the 2nd which uses tricks that might obscure what's going on, and the 3rd is just an alternate form of the 2nd.*

You can do this with structs and unnest.

A struct is a column that has columns inside of it. An initial approach would be to do this.

```
(
    df
        .select(
            'a',
            struc=pl.when(pl.col('a')==2)
            .then(
                pl.struct(
                    x=pl.lit('ham'),  # or pl.lit('ham').alias('x')
                    y=pl.lit('eggs'), # or pl.lit('eggs').alias('y')
                    z=pl.lit('fruit') # or pl.lit('fruit').alias('z')
                    )
            )
            .otherwise(
                pl.struct(
                    x=pl.col('x'), # or pl.col('x')
                    y=pl.col('y'), # or pl.col('y')
                    z=pl.col('z') # or pl.col('z')
                )
            )
        )
        .unnest('struc')
)
```

You'll notice that we're using a `select` and that we have to repeat the x,y,z assignment for both the `then` and `otherwise`. Using select is because when you unnest, if there are columns in common between the raw df and the columns in the struct, it'll give an error so you have to make sure to drop the originals (or use select and omit them). We have to be repetitive with assignment because the struct is empty so in the case where a!=2 then it'd just be null.

I called that an initial pass, here's a trick you can use with a walrus operator to make it less repetitive and use `with_columns`.

```
(
    df
        .with_columns(
            struc=pl.when(pl.col('a')==2)
            .then(
                pl.struct(**(new_vals:=dict(
                    x=pl.lit('ham'), 
                    y=pl.lit('eggs'), 
                    z=pl.lit('fruit')
                )))
            )
            .otherwise(
                pl.struct(
                    **{col:pl.col(col) for col in new_vals.keys()}
                )
            )
        )
        .drop(new_vals.keys())
        .unnest('struc')

)
```

One issue with this is that if you had columns after the x,y,z then this would push x,y,z to the end. To keep the column order, you have to record the order of the columns before you start ie `orig_cols=df.columns` and then after the `unnest` do `select(orig_cols)`

You can still use the walrus trick if you prefer `alias` syntax but it's a little bit weirder as you have to use the `.meta.output_name()` method. It would look like this instead.

```
(
    df
        .with_columns(
            struc=pl.when(pl.col('a')==2)
            .then(
                pl.struct(*(new_vals:=[
                    pl.lit('ham').alias('x'), 
                    pl.lit('eggs').alias('y'), 
                    pl.lit('fruit').alias('z')
                ]))
            )
            .otherwise(
                pl.struct(
                    *[pl.col(col.meta.output_name()) for col in new_vals]
                )
            )
        )
        .drop([col.meta.output_name() for col in new_vals])
        .unnest('struc')

)
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no real shorthand syntax in Polars for such an operation currently.

I guess the idea would be that `.then(x = ..., y = ..., z = ...)` could be supported.

[`.update()`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.update.html#polars.DataFrame.update) exists but constructing a 1-row frame ends up being more code.

```py
row = dict(x="ham", y="eggs", z="fruit")

df.with_columns(
    pl.when(pl.col("a") == 2).then(pl.lit(val)).otherwise(col).alias(col)
    for col, val in row.items()
)
```

```py
shape: (3, 4)
┌─────┬─────┬──────┬───────┐
│ a   ┆ x   ┆ y    ┆ z     │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ ---  ┆ ---   │
│ i64 ┆ str ┆ str  ┆ str   │
╞═════╪═════╪══════╪═══════╡
│ 1   ┆ foo ┆ bar  ┆ baz   │
│ 2   ┆ ham ┆ eggs ┆ fruit │
│ 3   ┆ baz ┆ baz  ┆ bar   │
└─────┴─────┴──────┴───────┘
```

If you wanted to create a helper, [`.pipe()`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.pipe.html#polars.DataFrame.pipe) could also be of interest.

```py
def update_row(df, when, then, literal=True):
    when = pl.when(when)
    then = dict(
        (col, when.then(pl.lit(val) if literal else val).otherwise(col))
        for col, val in then.items() 
    )
    return df.with_columns(**then)

df.pipe(update_row, 
    when = pl.col("a").eq(2),  
    then = dict(x="ham", y="eggs", z="fruit")
)
```